# How to return data from firebase cloud function and return async response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

What's up,
I want return from firebase function data.
My firebase function:

```
exports.genericEmail = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth && !context.auth.token.email) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("failed-precondition", "Must be logged with an email address")
  }

  return "Hello"

})
```

My request from https:

```
const callFirebaseFunction = event => {
  const addMessage = httpsCallable(functions, 'genericEmail');
  addMessage()
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result.data.output);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(`error: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
    });
}
```

In firebase console written that function was executed:
[Firebase console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1amw.png)
I receive in JS console **undefined**.
Also as function **async** I wanna get ability to track function's succeed/fail, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a `string` from the Cloud Function so `result.data` will be a string and trying to read the property `output` will log `undefined.`

Try returning an object instead as shown below:

```
exports.genericEmail = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  // function logic ...

  return { output: "Hello" }
})
```

Now `result.data.output` should log `Hello` on client side.

Comment: Oops, I really miss that tried log outa tribute that didn't have )

Comment: Also thanks for ability returning objects, that make things clear